# Can I use any 4R70W manual on any 4R70W transmission?

Tags: transmission, econoline, service-manual

I am doing this as a side project and I am aware it is very difficult.

I had some trouble finding a manual for my transmission. I am not 100% sure I even know what transmission I have. I pulled it out of a 2006 V8 E-150 so I think the transmission is a 4R70W/4R75W. I managed to find a manual for a 4R70W but it's for a 97 cougar.

So far the transmissions have been either very similar or identical. But I got to this part about removing 2 accumulators and 2 servos. My transmission has only one such ...cylinder.

Am I just not seeing it? Can you explain what the difference is between my 4R70W and the 4R70W in my manual? There are a lot of shady looking sites claiming to offer service manual downloads. Even out of those I cant find one for a 2006 Econoline. If you can point me to a place where I can find a proper manual I would be very appreciative.

What I'm looking at (not rotated the same, sorry):
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4jm5m3n314pu6i/4R70W%204R75W%20Overhaul.pdf?dl=0 see if it helps any.